Implementation of the Lanczos algorithm
I tried to implement Lanczos' algorithm in Mathematica:
LanczosAlgorithm[A_, m_, tol_] := Module[
  {a, b, n, v, V, w},
  
  n = Length[A];
  v = RandomReal[1, {n, 1}];
  v = v / Sqrt[(Transpose[v].v)[[1, 1]]];
  
  V = Table[0, m];
  V[[1]] = Transpose[v][[1]];
  
  w = A.v;
  a = (Transpose[w].v)[[1, 1]];
  w = w - a v;
  
  Do[b = Sqrt[(Transpose[w].w)[[1, 1]]];
     If[b > tol,
        v = w/b,      
        v = Transpose[{Orthogonalize[Join[A[[1 ;; i - 1]], 
                                          RandomReal[1, {1, n}]]][[i]]}]
       ];
     V[[i]] = Transpose[v][[1]];
     w = A.v;
     a = (Transpose[w].v)[[1, 1]];
     w = w - a v - b V[[i - 1]], {i, 2, m}];
  
  V.A.Transpose[V]]

So, I generated a symmetric real matrix A and tridiagonalized it into T:
{m, n, tol} = {10, 100, 10^-15};
A = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {n, n}];
A = Transpose[A].A;
T = LanczosAlgorithm[A, m, tol];

Finally, I compared the first m eigenvalues ​​of A with the eigenvalues ​​of T:
Eigenvalues[A, m]
Eigenvalues[T]

from which the following numerical values:

{12736.6, 11752.7, 11414.7, 11076.2, 10587.9, 9929.28, 9782.64, 9411.8, 9301.11, 8879.}


{12732., 11550.3, 10516.9, 8331.03, 7004.67, 5090.4, 2971.58, 1708.77, 662.432, 84.3267}

I can only note that there is a good similarity in the first eigenvalue, but the others are really different. This is essentially the problem discussed in this other thread 9 years ago now, but it didn't help me much to understand, also because I don't know the Python programming language.
My question is essentially the following: can the code I wrote be modified in such a way that the eigenvalues ​​of T are much closer to the first m eigenvalues ​​of A? Otherwise I can't understand the meaning of this algorithm, it would be easier for me to iterate the power method with deflation.

You don't need to know Python to follow the discussion in that question. Regarding your question, you can use the method to the "inverse" of the matrix tooth a shift to approximate better the lower eigenvalues. As discussed there.

The Lanczos algorithm is unstable, therefore we can't test it on arbitrary matrix. Next example shows that you code is valid
LanczosAlgorithm[A_, m_, tol_] := 
  Module[{a, b, n, v, V, w}, n = Length[A];
   v = RandomReal[1, {n, 1}];
   v = v/Sqrt[(Transpose[v] . v)[[1, 1]]];
   V = Table[0, m];
   V[[1]] = Transpose[v][[1]];
   w = A . v;
   a = (Transpose[w] . v)[[1, 1]];
   w = w - a v;
   Do[b = Sqrt[(Transpose[w] . w)[[1, 1]]];
    If[b > tol, v = w/b, 
     v = Transpose[{Orthogonalize[
          Join[A[[1 ;; i - 1]], RandomReal[1, {1, n}]]][[i]]}]];
    V[[i]] = Transpose[v][[1]];
    w = A . v;
    a = (Transpose[w] . v)[[1, 1]];
    w = w - a v - b V[[i - 1]], {i, 2, m}];
   V . A . Transpose[V]];

 A = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 5}, {3, 5, 6}}; {m, n, tol} = {3, 3, 
  10^-15};
T = LanczosAlgorithm[A, m, tol];

Eigenvalues[A // N]
Eigenvalues[T]

Out[]= {11.3448, -0.515729, 0.170915}

Out[]= {11.3448, -0.515729, 0.170915}

One more example
Clear[A];

 SeedRandom[123];

{m, n, tol} = {10, 10, 10^-5}; A = 
 RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {n, n}];
A = Transpose[A] . A;
T = LanczosAlgorithm[A, m, tol];

Eigenvalues[A // N, 10]
Eigenvalues[T]

{967.074, 793.783, 551.391, 310.252, 291.124, 129.408, \
84.4736, 61.6702, 13.7331, 0.303676}

{967.074, 793.783, 551.391, 310.252, 291.124, 129.408, \
84.4736, 61.6702, 13.7331, 0.303676}

Note, that with a small extension of the code, we can also compute eigensystem. As it well known, Lanczos algorithm is unstable in general case. For stabilization we can use the Gram-Schmidt process to orthogonalize intermediate set of vectors - see my answer here
